# Problem with second-line indent when enumerating.

Tags: xetex, enumitem

I am in trouble with the following situation.

[image]

However, this is what I actually got.
[image]

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[inline, shortlabels]{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item \begin{enumerate*}[leftmargin=*,labelindent=16pt, series = tobecont, itemjoin = \\, labelindent=20pt]
    \item What is the flow rate  in terms of the velocity and area at state 2?
    \item What does the energy equation reduce to in terms of the velocity, area, and elevation at state 2?
    \item What is the value of the elevation $z_{2}$?
    \item What is the area of the nozzle discharge $A_{2}$?
   \item The energy equation is non-linear in the unknown velocity $V_{2}$. All of the other parameters are known. Using an equation solving routine on your calculator or computer, what is the value of $V_{2}$?
   \item What is the volume flow rate through the nozzle?
   \end{enumerate*}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

My problem is, I used `series = tobecont` to prevent line break after the item "**5.**" and added `labelindent=16pt` to adjust the indent on the second line, but it seems that `labelindent` command didn't work with `series = tobecont`. Is there any way to fix this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why are you using an inline list when you obviously don't want it to be inline? Removing all your settings seems to give the output you want:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[inline, shortlabels]{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item \begin{enumerate}
    \item What is the flow rate  in terms of the velocity and area at state 2?
    \item What does the energy equation reduce to in terms of the velocity, area, and elevation at state 2?
    \item What is the value of the elevation $z_{2}$?
    \item What is the area of the nozzle discharge $A_{2}$?
   \item The energy equation is non-linear in the unknown velocity $V_{2}$. All of the other parameters are known. Using an equation solving routine on your calculator or computer, what is the value of $V_{2}$?
   \item What is the volume flow rate through the nozzle?
   \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I thought it too complicated. I thought that an enumerate structure followed by another enumerate system should use inline structure. That's why I used the wrong command. Thank you!